# How to get root value from multiple hierarchical rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 'New Tenant' and 'Previous Tenant' columns. This table has current tenant and previous tenant id's in a table with values as below

[image]

how can i write a SQL to get first root tenant(first Occupant) for a property as new column for each record as below

[image]

First tenant in a property is t0000123 then tenant  t0012345 moved and then t0008518 moved then t0020198. so primary occupant for all these tenants is t0000123 . Similarly for another property for tenant t0020197 first tenant is t0010672

Comment: This look like a job for a recursive common table expression (CTE). What have you tried? Tip: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE should do:

```
with n (new_tenant, previous_tenant, c_tenant, lvl) as (
  select new_tenant, previous_tenant, previous_tenant, 1 from tenant
  union all
  select n.new_tenant, n.previous_tenant, t.previous_tenant, 1
    from tenant t
    join n on n.new_tenant = t.previous_tenant
),
m (new_tenant, max_lvl) as (
  select new_tenant, max(lvl)
    from n
    group by new_tenant
)
select n.*
  from n
  join m on m.max_lvl = n.lvl
```